# Stem direction on voices in Guitar Pro 7

Tags: software, guitar-pro

How do I keep the stem direction same on each different Voice on Guitar Pro 7, GP7?

I have used GP7 moderately.  I feel there is a setting to lock stem direction on each Voice.  When I input notes on different bar keeping the same voice GP7 automatically changes the direction of the stems and this is taking time to correct.

Comment: Are you entering the voices in numerical order for each measure? I've notice in other software that if I enter voice 2 before voice 1, the stems will be in the wrong direction (though they correct themselves when entering voice 1).

Comment: In addition to what Aaron suggests, it's always good practice to *first* enter everything related to basic notation, all voices, all parts and articulations, then add any indication about technique, lyrics, etc; *finally* fix all "aesthetic", like stem directions. Maybe this is not about this specific issue, but it's worth mentioning anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: **There is no way to force stems to automatically only go one way in GP7.**

---

Workaround: **You can manually change stem direction.** You will avoid giving yourself a headache if you either do this all at the end of in batches, rather than as you're writing, because it can be a very tedious process and really only serves an aesthetic purpose ([as pointed out by musicamante](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/117255/stem-direction-on-voices-in-guitar-pro-7#comment210241_117255)).

Take this (admittedly contrived) example, where one voice overlaps the other:

[image: bar lines from multiple voices crossing over each other]

In Guitar Pro 7, there are two options to manipulate stems: "Automatic Stems" and "Invert Stems". In cases where you want to invert stems for a particular voice, you can select a specific note (or highlight a section), and select "Invert Stems" in the left-hand Edition Palette here:

[image: Edition Palette with "Automatic Stems" and "Invert Stems" circled]

Alternatively, this option can be found in `Note` -> `Design` -> `Invert Stems`

The output of this looks like:

[image: bar lines from multiple voices not crossing over each other]